# How to "populate" a range of values in different rows, in R?

Tags: r, input, range, populate

I have a data frame with thousands of rows, similar to:

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(ID=c(1:10),
                from=c(sort(runif(10, min=1000, max=10000))),
                to=c(sort(runif(10, min=5000, max=20000))))
```

In this data frame I have a range (from-to), and I need some intermediate values, it could be a number every 1000 units. The desired output is a data frame with the ID column and a row for each value in the range, like:

```
ID number
1  1556.076
1  2556.076
1  3556.076
1  4556.076
1  5556.076
1  6556.076
1  7556.076
1  7648.351 # From column "to"
2  2815.137
2  3815.137
2  4815.137
2  5815.137
2  6815.137
2  7815.137
2  8089.619 # From column "to"
# And so on…
```

Can anybody help? I've been trying in several different ways, but couldn't figure out an effective way to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a `list` column by looping across the corresponding 'from', 'to' columns with `map2`, apply the `seq` and then `unnest` the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  transmute(ID, number = map2(from, to, ~ seq(.x, .y, by = 1000))) %>% 
  unnest(c(number))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 80 x 2
#      ID number
#   <int>  <dbl>
# 1     1  1556.
# 2     1  2556.
# 3     1  3556.
# 4     1  4556.
# 5     1  5556.
# 6     1  6556.
# 7     1  7556.
# 8     2  2815.
# 9     2  3815.
#10     2  4815.
# … with 70 more rows
```

---

Or using `base R` with `Map`

```
lst1 <- Map(seq, MoreArgs = list(by = 1000), df$from, df$to)
data.frame(ID = rep(df$ID, lengths(lst1)), number = unlist(lst1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, .(number = do.call(seq, c(.SD, by = 1e3))), ID]
    ID    number
 1:  1  1556.076
 2:  1  2556.076
 3:  1  3556.076
 4:  1  4556.076
 5:  1  5556.076
 6:  1  6556.076
 7:  1  7556.076
 8:  2  2815.137
 9:  2  3815.137
10:  2  4815.137
11:  2  5815.137
12:  2  6815.137
13:  2  7815.137
14:  3  3389.578
15:  3  4389.578
16:  3  5389.578
17:  3  6389.578
18:  3  7389.578
19:  3  8389.578
20:  3  9389.578
21:  3 10389.578
22:  4  4349.115
23:  4  5349.115
24:  4  6349.115
25:  4  7349.115
26:  4  8349.115
27:  4  9349.115
28:  4 10349.115
29:  5  6155.680
30:  5  7155.680
31:  5  8155.680
32:  5  9155.680
33:  5 10155.680
34:  5 11155.680
35:  5 12155.680
36:  6  6662.026
37:  6  7662.026
38:  6  8662.026
39:  6  9662.026
40:  6 10662.026
41:  6 11662.026
42:  6 12662.026
43:  6 13662.026
44:  6 14662.026
45:  7  6947.180
46:  7  7947.180
47:  7  8947.180
48:  7  9947.180
49:  7 10947.180
50:  7 11947.180
51:  7 12947.180
52:  7 13947.180
53:  7 14947.180
54:  8  9085.507
55:  8 10085.507
56:  8 11085.507
57:  8 12085.507
58:  8 13085.507
59:  8 14085.507
60:  8 15085.507
61:  8 16085.507
62:  9  9173.870
63:  9 10173.870
64:  9 11173.870
65:  9 12173.870
66:  9 13173.870
67:  9 14173.870
68:  9 15173.870
69:  9 16173.870
70: 10  9502.077
71: 10 10502.077
72: 10 11502.077
73: 10 12502.077
74: 10 13502.077
75: 10 14502.077
76: 10 15502.077
77: 10 16502.077
78: 10 17502.077
79: 10 18502.077
80: 10 19502.077
    ID    number
```